# excel activex text box no scroll bar appearing

Tags: excel, vba, activex

Please can someone tell me why is the scroll bar not appearing when I have it set to 2 (vertical), multiline = true, wordwrap=true, enterkeybehaviour=true and the text will not fit in the textbox? I simply cannot get the scroll bar to appear.

Update: the scroll bar appears when I go to edit and write anything further in the box! Note it was already overspilling, and this happens regardless 
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the described property values. Can you add a screenshot showing the textbox with enough content to overflow, along with the *Properties* toolwindow?

Comment: Hi, I would like to, but how can I take a screenshot of properties when I have to select the textbox to bring that up, it only takes a screenshot of the textbox? Weirdly when I go on edit textbox the scrollbar appears, but is absent otherwise

Comment: Hit [Print Screen], paste in MSPaint, select the relevant area, paste into your post :)

Comment: still just pastes the text box?  In the meantime see my edit.

Comment: Ok.. so, I'm not sure what the problem is anymore

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Because it only appears after I edit it. I would like it to appear as soon as I paste the too-long text in

Comment: hmm maybe it's only meant to show the scroll bar when you click on it...

Comment: it would look better if it always showed the scroll